# i18next plurals using count returned an object instead of string

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

Trying to figure out plurals with `i18next-react`. I must be missing something really obvious. I get the error `Results in key 'generic.rule-group (en)' returned an object instead of string.`

Thanks in advance

**resources.json**

```json
{
  "en": {
    "default": {
      "generic.rule-group": {
        "one": "Rule group",
        "other": "Rule groups"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**jsx**

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';


export const Test = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation()

  // Results in key 'generic.rule-group (en)' returned an object instead of string.
  return <h1>{t('generic.rule-group', { count: 1 })}</h1>
}
```

**i18next-config.js**

```js
i18next
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    ns,
    fallbackNS: 'default',
    defaultNS: ns,
    lng: 'en',
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    resources,
    keySeparator: false,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/plurals), I think the resources json keys should be:

```
{
  "en": {
    "default": {
      "generic.rule-group": "Rule group",
      "generic.rule-group_plural": "Rule groups"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Did some more reading. I'm using POEditor which outputs plurals in `CLDR` plurals? Apparently that isn't supported in i18next.

Comment: @MattThomas Indeed, you can read more on this topic in the following issue: https://github.com/i18next/i18next/issues/1202

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who came across this issue, please use `other` and `one` instead of `plural`.

```
  {
    "en": {
       "default": {
       "generic.rule-group": "Rule group",
       "generic.rule-group_other": "Rule groups"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may verify your key. If you have nested key staructure then pass the exact key to avoid this error. For example,

```
"parent": {
   "child1": "Child 1",
   "child2": "Child 2"
}
```

Then pass the key as `"parent.child1"` or `"parent.child2"`.