# i18n using keys as object keys instead of string

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I have a translations constant that holds all the keys, that way I can access the translations by typing the key so it avoids mistakes.

however I am experiencing an issue whenever I am using the translations imported from that Translations file.

`i18next::translator: missingKey en-US translations Phone Phone`

my i18n file looks like:

```
import i18n from 'i18next'
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector'
import moment from 'moment'

import {TRANSLATION} from './translations'

i18n.use(LanguageDetector).init({
  // we init with resources
  resources: {
    en: {
      translations: TRANSLATION.EN,
    },
  },
  fallbackLng: 'en-US',
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',

  // have a common namespace used around the full app
  ns: ['translations'],
  defaultNS: 'translations',
  keySeparator: false, // we use content as keys
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false, // not needed for react!!
    formatSeparator: ',',
    format: function(value, formatting, lng) {
      if (value instanceof Date) return moment(value).format(formatting)
      return value.toString()
    },
  },
  react: {
    wait: true,
  },
})

export default i18n
```

the file  with the keys that I am using on the form

```
export const TRANSLATION = {

  EN:{
    phone: 'Phone',
  }
}
```

the component where I am using the Keys:

```
import i18n, {T_KEYS} from '@/services/i18n'

const Component=()=>{
return(
   <Form.Item
            name="phone"
            label={i18n.t(T_KEYS.phone)}
            rules={rules.phone}
          >
            <Input />
          </Form.Item>

)
```

I believe that for some reason the component is being rendered before the translations keys have accessed, so the Keys are missing and the message is displayed but I am not 100% sure, I tried adding `Object.keys(TRANSLATIONS.EN)` && before `i18n.use(LanguageDetector).init({`, but it des not seem to solve the situation, I was wondering if anyone had a similar issue or idea since after browsing through documentation and repository I couldn't find any answer to what is happening.

thanks in advance

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Comment: You can check this for the answer and explaination - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76836364/3660648

Answer (score 1):

the problem for this issue for those of you searching for a answer, is that when using the T_KEYS.phone, we are sending the key Phone, that does not exist on our translations file, this is causing the error with the translations.